# Laravel testing. Reset controller DI while test

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit, laravel-testing

I have a Laravel controller with DI in

```
__construct(Model1 $m1, Model2 $m2, $SomeService $s) {
 $this->m1 = $m1;
 $this->m2 = $m2;
 $this->s = $s;
}
```

I have an API test with call or endpoint based on this controller. I'm doing 8 same API url calls with different payload. It seems z controller constructor process 1 time and after that works with constructed dependencies.

```
$response1 = $this->actingAs($admin,'api')->json('POST', '/api/someURL', $payload1);

$response2 = $this->actingAs($admin,'api')->json('POST', '/api/someURL', $payload2);

$responseN = $this->actingAs($admin,'api')->json('POST', '/api/someURL', $payloadN);
```

Can I somehow set dependencies before each API call in test?

Comment: Can it be that `SomeService` is registered as a singleton?

Comment: SomeService is just a user class in App\Providers;

Comment: @Amade I mean, I have not made something special with this class....

Comment: Guys, what about using Mockery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unset the controller instance between request from the route using:

```
$response1 = $this->actingAs($admin,'api')->json('POST', '/api/someURL', $payload1);

// unset the controller
$this->app->get(Illuminate\Routing\Route::class)->controller = null;

$response2 = $this->actingAs($admin,'api')->json('POST', '/api/someURL', $payload2);

// unset the controller
$this->app->get(Illuminate\Routing\Route::class)->controller = null;

$responseN = $this->actingAs($admin,'api')->json('POST', '/api/someURL', $payloadN);
```

Why?

In [Illuminate\Routing\Router](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L634) Laravel binds the current route to the container:

```
protected function findRoute($request)
{
    $this->current = $route = $this->routes->match($request);
    $this->container->instance(Route::class, $route);
    return $route;
}
```

and when the route controller is run in [Illuminate\Routing\Route](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L228), the controller instance is stored in Route object:

```
public function getController()
{
    if (! $this->controller) {
        $class = $this->parseControllerCallback()[0];
        $this->controller = $this->container->make(ltrim($class, '\\'));
    }
    return $this->controller;
}
```

Comment: Illuminate\Container\EntryNotFoundException:

E:\repos\dcp-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:613
E:\repos\dcp-laravel\tests\Unit\ProposalRoundTest.php:183

Comment: I hope u do not ask me to change smth direct in Illuminate\ folder?)

Comment: no, the later part is only the reasoning behind the answer.

Comment: Are you doing `$this->app->get(Route::class)->controller = null;` after you hit the route at least once?

Comment: ok, it works. But anyway, it looks a little cheaty) I've expected Mockery or smth like this....

Comment: how did you fix this Illuminate\Container\EntryNotFoundException ?